# problems in regex php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i need to extract the next value (E002073) in a html content but mi regex doesnt work, only work in regex101 dot com

mi regex its `/digo de reserva: <\/td>\n[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]*)<td>(.*)<\/td>/`

and the code example is https://xrg.es/#13csj2l

any suggestions?

Comment: Use DOMDocument and DOMXPath, don't use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

That answer works in regex buddy 4. Are you sure it's the regex and not the PHP implemented?

Here is a code-snippet generated by RegexBuddy4

```
if (preg_match('%\Adigo de reserva: <\/td>\n[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]*)<td>(.*)<\/td>\z%m', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Personally, I would use this pattern instead:

```
digo de reserva: <\/td>\n[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]*)<td>\K(.*)(?=<\/td>)
```

Or if it works for you,

```
digo de reserva:.*?<td>\K(.*?)(?=<\/td>)
```

#### Updated Answer:

I've never messed with PHP before and was having trouble escaping the double-quotes in this snippet, so I did it manually. I'm sure you can figure that one out. I was able to get this working in [Teh Playground](http://www.tehplayground.com/#lVGvMQXQf):

```
// example code

$subject = addslashes("<td style=\"border-right: 1px solid #cccccc\">C&oacute;digo de reserva: </td>
                <td>E002073</td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>");


if (preg_match('/digo de reserva:.*?<td>\K(.*?)(?=<\/td>)/s', $subject)) {
    print_r("Successful match");
} else {
    print_r("Match attempt failed");
}
```

Comment: nope, is not a php problem, i have a question, why when i can try the regex created from regex buddy 4 doesnt work in php, i cant understand that  because the regex are created with pcre

Comment: Hi @CamiloOrtúzar I went ahead and updated the answer using Teh Playground. If it works for you as it works for me, please accept this answer! :) The link, I believe, takes you to the actual snippet I made.